# After updating new app on play store it is showing old verison only

Tags: android, google-play

Today I had updated one application on play store. This app was present previously on play store, but before some months we had removed this application. Now after some code changes we had release this app again for 20% user. Now the problem is on play store it is showing old application(which we had removed some months before). Does we miss something or it will take 2-3 hr to reflect the same.

Comment: It'll take a few hours until changes are visible to the public. You should get a notification in the console when the changes are published.

Comment: @Henry. Thanks for comment. I know while updating it takes around 3-4 hr. But still confused why it is showing old version. It should not show old version right?

Comment: It's showing the old version because of google play caches, it can take up to 24 hours for users to see the new version

Answer (score 2):

The developer doesn't actually have to change the 'Version' number that shows in the Play Store, they only need to increment a build version (which is not visible anywhere in the Play Store) so the version that is shown may not change. This allows for quick fixes to be pushed out without incrementing the actual version number.

**Refer this link:**
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/app-updation-google-play-store-wants-to-update-an-older-version-of-app-when-lat

Answer (score 0):

In my case my current app version is versionCode 28,but some of my users are installing versionCode 17 or 21.Once they install the old one,we are usinf FirebaseRemoteConfig inside all of our apps so we are prompting to update to latest 28th version.But still i couldn't find the reason for Old app's availablity in Playstore.Its annoying